# List(OF T).Contains Problem (Search through String or Integer Props of the Class)

Tags: vb.net, list

List(Of T).Contains function help.

Here is my simple object.

```
Public Class Person
Name as string
Age as Integer
End Class
```

In the Sub:

```
Dim Person as new Person
Person.Name = "John"
Person.Age = 32

Dim myPersonList as new List(of Person)
myPersonList.Add(Person)
```

How would I exactly look up if the List Contains a person named "John" with the myPersonList.Contains() function,  Or how would i look up myPersonListContains(AGE)???.  I can't neccessarily put "John" or an Age because the Contains function is asking for the Person Class, and not the string "John".  I'd like to use this method instead of writing a function that iterates through every Persons "Name"

Answer (score 2):

I used the `Find` method of `List(Of T)`. I made your `Name` and `Age` in the `Person` class real Properties.

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
End Class

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim myPersonList As New List(Of Person)

    Dim p1 As New Person
    p1.Name = "John"
    p1.Age = 32
    myPersonList.Add(p1)
    Dim p2 As New Person
    p2.Name = "Mathew"
    p2.Age = 73
    myPersonList.Add(p2)
    Dim p3 As New Person
    p3.Name = "Mark"
    p3.Age = 90
    myPersonList.Add(p3)
    Dim foundInList = myPersonList.Find(Function(x) x.Name = "John")
    If foundInList Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("John not found")
    Else
        Dim JohnsAgeIs = foundInList.Age
        Debug.Print(JohnsAgeIs.ToString)
        '32 appears in Immediate window
    End If
End Sub
```

Corrected per comment by @jmcilhinney. Without checking first if a person was returned by `.Find` a NRE could occur.

Comment: To get the same result as `Contains`, i.e. a `Boolean` indicating whether a matching item exists, you'd have to test whether the result was not `Nothing`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Brain is still thawing out from the Texas deep freeze. Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected the code. I also read the question incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your item type implements `IEquatable(Of T)`, `Contains` will only check for reference equality. If you do implement `IEquatable(Of Person)` in the `Person` class, that implementation will be specific and unchanging, so you still can't compare in different ways at different times. What you should do is use the LINQ `Any` method instead, e.g.

```vb
If myPersonList.Any(Function(p) p.Name = "John") Then
    '...
End If

If myPersonList.Any(Function(p) p.Age = 32) Then
    '...
End If
```

Comment: Can this same method be used for the List.remove function???

Comment: The `Any` extension method that I used here works like `Contains`, in that it returns a `Boolean` to indicate whether any items match the specified criteria. The `Find` method proposed in another answer is a bit different in that it actually gets the first matching item, but you use the same type of predicate to specify the criteria. It works just like the `FirstOrDefault` extension method. There is also a `RemoveAll` method that takes a similar predicate and removes all matching items.